# Getting zmin zmax of a raster parameter in a tool validation in ArcGIS Desktop 10.7 toolbox Python script

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, tool-validation

I am developing a Python tool (my first one).
The tool has 3 input parameters:

1. a raster
2. z min
3. z max

I am trying to get automatically z min and z max after the user specify the raster using the validation script but I got this error:

> TypeError: expected a raster or layer

This is my code (commented lines are other attempts I tried without results):

```
def updateParameters(self):
"""Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
has been changed."""

if self.params[0].altered:
  if self.params[0].value:
    #rst_ds = self.params[0]
    rst_ds = self.params[0].value
    self.params[1].value = arcpy.Raster(rst_ds).minimum

    #self.params[2].value = arcpy.Raster(rst_ds.replace('\\','/')).maximum
    #arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(rst_ds, "rst_lyr")
    #self.params[1].value = arcpy.Raster("rst_lyr").minimum

return
```

Comment: Is this from a Python Script Tool in a standard toolbox (`*.tbx`) or from a tool in a Python Toolbox (`*.pyt`)?

Comment: It's a Python Script Tool in a standard toolbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there! Firstly ensure your parameters are their correct data type as shown below:

[image: Parameters]

The correct code in the validation function updateParameters would be:

```py
  def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    if self.params[0].altered:
      if self.params[0].value:
        rst_ds = self.params[0].valueAsText
        ra = arcpy.Raster(rst_ds)
        self.params[1].value = ra.minimum
        self.params[2].value = ra.maximum
    return
```

Comment: It works! Thank you @Hornbydd